# How to get rows that doesn't have values start with specific pattern in a pipe delimited file?

Tags: linux, awk, text

I am trying to get only the rows that don't have values start with a certain patterns.

Input file (test_file.txt)

```
USER1|AR-45233|
USER4|AR-32133|
USER1|45232|
USER1|AF-45233|
USER2|AR-12321|
SYSTEM1|A9-12312|
USER1|AP-67655|
```

Expected output (test_filtered.txt)

```
USER1|45232|
SYSTEM1|A9-12312|
```

I tried this and it appears to be working. Is there a better way to achieve the same?

```
awk -F "|" '{if ($2!~/AP-/ && $2!~/AR-/ && $2!~/AF-/) {print $0}}' test_file.txt > test_filtered.txt
```

I asked this question because when I want to extract just the rows that don't match the condition above and write to a separate file like this, I'm not able to do so.

```
awk -F "|" '{if ($2~/AP-/ && $2~/AR-/ && $2~/AF-/) {print $0}}' test_file.txt > test_to_remove.txt
```

Comment: maybe `awk -F\| '$2!~/^A[PRF]-/'`

Comment: Thank you. It worked just fine both ways.

Comment: your 2nd script should obviously use "or" instead of "and" if you want to write it that way ;-) the complement of "not short and not fat" is "short __or__ fat", not "short __and__ fat".

Answer (score 1):

using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) is

```
mlr --csv --fs "|" --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output filter -x -S '$2=~"^A[RFP]-"' input >output
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$  grep -v '|A[PRF]-' test_file.txt
```

Is a grep based solution.

```
$ sed -e '/^[^|]*[|]A[PRF]-/d' test_file.txt > test_filtered.txt
```

And in case the input is just 2-field wide, then this will do:

```
$ sed -e '/[|]A[PRF]-/d' test_file.txt > test_filtered.txt
```

Note: Iam writing `[|]` even where a plain `|` 
Would have sufficed. This is to make it work in both regular and extended regex modes without altering. IOW, this will work for POSIX and GNU sed xtended regex.